# Trouble with aliasing in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently doing a wrapper over CQL and faced trouble with renaming property keys i.e. aliasing. Here's playground with all needed code and 3 cases: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-geJFgmhY4ElgglnyIbGnDTrO84uQcWBZBV6DycULAAEwGHRUgMVgzFsRxXE8RUfGmNElkiYQYk5VJxlpDJjLYE5SFKQcTDqTgmnwNpiFpY4BmZJY4V9VZWA2XZDlYDV02udI7meY83m+Vg-lbIFwUXaFW04ECPhJSlQKrTyT7RVl4nxd4+WWIVWDFahZUoNAlWQ9VU3+AAzI19GOtAbWAKDkjnCsds1qRpAhLb5n3rSGT3CVoOIxrZWD2RjCkESgp0hB5koXT5iHXXhd35g9sW9c9iVoO9n15WcQOsEVyElVjENQ0AA)

If possible, change only type part of code. '1' is db connection client, so 'as unknown as ***' will be anyway in code.
Here`s a code:

```
class Test {
  constructor(data: Test) {
    this.first = data.first;
    this.numero = data.numero;
    this.test_id = data.test_id;
  }
  test_id: string;
  numero: number;
  first: string;
}

export type SelectFields<T> = {
  field: keyof T;
  alias?: string;
};

type SelectResult<
  T,
  S extends SelectFields<T>[],
> = S[number]['alias'] extends string
  ? { [K in S[number]['field'] as S[number]['alias']]: T[K] }
  : { [K in S[number]['field']]: T[K] };

const findByField = async <T extends Test, S extends SelectFields<Test>[]>(params?: {
    select?: S;
    where?: any[];
    limit?: number;
  }) => {
    // 1 is mock for client-db request logic, in production will be like 'return client.query... as unknown as Type for this problem', actual values will be equal to my described type.
    return 1 as unknown as SelectResult<Test, S>;
  };

const test1 = () => {
  /* ❌ - must be { number_alias: number, id_alias: string }
  const result: Promise<{
    [x: string]: string | number;
  }>
  */
  const result = findByField({
      select: [{ field: 'numero', alias: 'number_alias'}, {field: 'test_id', alias: 'id_alias'}],
    })
  return result  
}  

const test2 = () => {
  /* ❌ - must be { numero: number, id_alias: string }
  const result: Promise<{
    test_id: string;
    numero: number;
  }>
  */
  const result = findByField({
      select: [{ field: 'numero' }, {field: 'test_id', alias: 'id_alias'}],
    })
  return result  
}  

const test3 = () => {
  /* ✅
  const result: Promise<{
    test_id: string;
    numero: number;
  }>
  */
  const result = findByField({
      select: [{ field: 'numero'}, {field: 'test_id'}],
    })
  return result  
}
```

But got stuck with results.

Comment: ① Please put all relevant code as plaintext in the question. A playground link is a nice supplement but it doesn't suffice to be a [mre]. ② Once you do that: you have several issues here but I'd say the big one is that you want the type parameter to be `const` to infer the string literal types.  If I fix that plus the others I get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NlzZOW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (after you [edit] to include the [mre]). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Wow, that's exactly what I was trying to do, your solution completely covers the question!

Comment: I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Oh, I see that you've added lots of code that is not from your playground link and if put this code in an IDE I get tons of errors. Maybe I wasn't clear.  Please make sure that the code in the question is a [mre]. It needs to be reproducible, so if stuff from your playground link is important, it should be in the question.  But it also needs to be *minimal*. I could probably do the edit for you, if you'd like, but it would be nice if you could just put your playground code in the question yourself, as plaintext.

Comment: @jcalz You're right, my project's code is way complicated and 90% of the code doesn't relate to the problem, so i've updated it by pasting playground code here, thanks for help!
Also tested it with my project's code, works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important issue with your code is that the compiler doesn't expect you to care about the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `field` and `alias` subproperties of the `select` parameter. It will tend to infer just `string` and that stops everything from working. You can change that by using [a `const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters):

```
declare const findByField:
  <const S extends SelectFields<Test>[]>(params?: {
    select?: S;
    where?: any[];
    limit?: number;
  }) => Promise<SelectResult<Test, S>>;
```

Now TypeScript will try to infer `S` as the narrowest type it can, including the exact values passed in for `field` and `alias` and even the order of the array elements (although I don't think you care about that).

After this you only need to implement `SelectResult` so that it actually matches the key with the value properly.  You were already using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) but still iterating over *key types*, when it turns out that you can iterate over arbitrary [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) as long as the thing after the `as` is a key type.  (So in `{[A in B as C]: D}` you don't need `B` to be keylike, as long as `C` is keylike.)  So you can do this:

```
type SelectResult<
  T,
  S extends SelectFields<T>[],
> = { [U in S[number]
  as U['alias'] extends string ? U['alias'] : U['field']
  ]: T[U['field']] }
```

Note that since this is now just a single mapped type, it's possible IntelliSense will preserve the `SelectResult` name when displaying results. To avoid that you can do a no-op [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with the empty object type to prompt the type display to simplify further:

```
type SelectResult<
  T,
  S extends SelectFields<T>[],
> = { [U in S[number]
  as U['alias'] extends string ? U['alias'] : U['field']
  ]: T[U['field']] } & {};
```

Okay, let's test it:

```
const result1 = findByField({
  select: [
    { field: 'numero', alias: 'number_alias' },
    { field: 'test_id', alias: 'id_alias' }],
})
// const result1: Promise<{ number_alias: number; id_alias: string; }>

const result2 = findByField({
  select: [
    { field: 'numero' },
    { field: 'test_id', alias: 'id_alias' }
  ]
})
// const result2: Promise<{ numero: number; id_alias: string; }>

const result3 = findByField({
  select: [
    { field: 'numero' },
    { field: 'test_id' }],
})
// const result3: Promise<{ numero: number; test_id: string; }>
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-BWr9u1PoAHFEDqLPEfMMpfvB1OVnoNuDgAmQshYvix5litVlsNZ1kOf5dqYeh9t4A5cKB-QjmOjgTmesIzr2PiUkuq7ri+b5IO+e6RgIR4nhBOAxNo8SBleN6QHeiw+E+6C4XsBwAMxfqKv7NOWnCAWQwGDg2YEji2kH9iBwnwaO9hIQuZzBthG6Cq+rFIGxhEHsRx7nmRFFaFRl6IdQ9HhIx6BAA)